# Is it possible to use multiple p4aliases files in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to use multiple p4alias files, like one personal p4alias file and one project related? I do not see a way to source or concatenate multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practical answer: not really, no -- you should just copy and paste the project alias file into your personal alias file.  A fun trick here is to keep the aliases file in the depot, so you can use merging to pull project-level changes into your personal file without having your own changes go back.

Impractical answer: run something in the background that will concatenate the files together for you and surface them as a single p4aliases file, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/762590/can-i-create-a-symlink-esque-file-to-merge-two-files-together